# Printer Friendly page not working with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, window.open

i m trying to pickup contents of a div and open it in new window using window.open so user can print this printer friendly page. i have got the code somewhere on the net and made some modifications. below is the code snippet

```
function printpage() {
      var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
      disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=650, height=600, left=100, top=25";
      var content_vlue = document.getElementById("memo_data").innerHTML;
      var somestyle = '<style type="text/css"> #memotxt p {padding:0 0 0 0;margin:5px 0 0 0;}</style>';  

  var docprint=window.open("","sa",disp_setting); 
   docprint.document.open();
   docprint.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Inter Office Memo</title>');
   docprint.document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/style.css"');
   //docprint.document.write(somestyle);
   docprint.document.write('</head><body><fieldset style="border:none;"><div class="memo-report-top"');          
   docprint.document.write(content_vlue);          
   docprint.document.write('</div></fieldset></body></html>'); 
   docprint.document.close(); 
   docprint.focus(); 

     }
```

when i open this page in firefox it works exactly the way it is supposed to but when i open page in IE8 and press print button that triggers printpage() function. a new window pops up with ugly looks. i have also called a css file in printer friendly page but when i examine it in IE8 developer tool it shows me just css properties applied on body and fieldset. rest of properties are not there.
suggestions and help are highly appreciated
thanks

Comment: Why not just load the same page in the popup and then use a print only stylesheet to perform the styling? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: because that would require another css just to hide other parts of the page. i think its better to put necessary content in print page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the div tag was left open in the following code line

```
docprint.document.write('</head><body><fieldset style="border:none;"><div class="memo-report-top"');
```

closing it resolved the problem
thanks everyone for ur input 
regrds
adeel